# Shiny: dynamic checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, responsive

I'm building a Shiny app and I would like to add a dynamic "checkboxGroup" which depends on some other input. More precisely, the user can upload N files, the app makes some calculations, then the output is a table with N columns (one for each file uploaded). At this point I would like the user to be able to select only certain columns, i.e. the ones he/she would like to consider, then the table should update according to the user's choice.

I had a look at some shiny apps on the web, and the closest solution is probably something like
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html

but unfortunately in that example we have

```
checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                       names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
```

where diamonds is "known", whereas in my case I don't know how many files the user will upload and so how many columns my table will have.

Any ideas?
Cheers

**EDITED:** 
Here there is the portion of code I'm reffering to. It works, the user can upload N excel files with same number of rows. The app returns a tab with N columns (the second column of each file uploaded). 
Ideally, now I would like to add N check boxes (all selected initially), and the user can uncheck the columns he/she doesn't want to consider. Say he/she uncheck 2 columns, then the tab changes into a tab with N-2 columns.

Thanks again

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 350,
  sidebarMenu(
    tags$style(HTML(".sidebar-menu li a { color: #f4f8e8; }")),
    menuItem("Computations",tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("file-text-o"))
  ))


body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(".content-wrapper {background-color: #c3f9fa;}"),
  style = "color: black;",
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "tab1",
      h2("upload files"),
      tags$style(HTML(" .progress-bar { background-color: #1dbcbf; }")),
      fileInput("csvs",
                label="Upload CSVs here",
                multiple = TRUE),
      textInput(inputId="num_files", 
                label="number of files uploaded", 
                value = "", 
                width = NULL, 
                placeholder = NULL),
      actionButton(inputId = "display_tab", label = "Display Tab after computations"),
      box(title = "tab after computations:",tableOutput("all_cols"),width = 100),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId="show_vars", "Columns to keep:", choices = "selectedData", selected = "selectedData")
    )))

dbHeader <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Exercise')


ui <- dashboardPage(

  skin = "black",
  dbHeader,
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=260*1024^2)

  computations <- function(num_files, db){
    num_files <- as.numeric(num_files)
    N <- nrow(db)/num_files  #number of rows for 1 file (they all have same size)
    tab_to_be_displayed <- db[1:N,2]

    for(j in (1:(num_files - 1))){
      left <- j*N+1
      right <- (j+1)*N
      tab_to_be_displayed <- cbind(tab_to_be_displayed, db[left:right,2])
    }
    return(tab_to_be_displayed)
  }


  mycsvs<-reactive({
    rbindlist(lapply(input$csvs$datapath, fread),
              use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  })



  selectedData <- reactive({
    names(computations(input$num_files, mycsvs()))
  })



  observeEvent(input$display_tab,{
    numero <- input$num_files
    comp_tab <- computations(numero, mycsvs())
    output$all_cols <- renderTable(comp_tab, align = 'c', rownames = TRUE, colnames = TRUE, digits = 3)
  })


}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What have you built so far on this? The checkboxes can be dynamically created and modified as suggested by @SmokeyShakers. If you can share a basic example of what you have in mind, perhaps we can fill in what you need for the checkboxes.

Comment: I'm going to edit the original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code a bit to demonstrate how the group checkboxes could work.

In simplifying, I kept the data as a `list` from the `csv` files. Then for computations extracted the second column from all data frames in the list, then used `select` to show columns based on the checkboxes.

The checkbox items are based on the names of the second columns of the data, with a default of all selected.

Instead of entering the number of files that were read, it is now computed based on the length of the `list` of data.

Let me know if this is closer to what you need.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 350,
  sidebarMenu(
    tags$style(HTML(".sidebar-menu li a { color: #f4f8e8; }")),
    menuItem("Computations",tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("file-text-o"))
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(".content-wrapper {background-color: #c3f9fa;}"),
  style = "color: black;",
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "tab1",
      h2("upload files"),
      tags$style(HTML(" .progress-bar { background-color: #1dbcbf; }")),
      fileInput("csvs",
                label="Upload CSVs here",
                multiple = TRUE),
      textOutput("numfiles"),
      box(title = "tab after computations:",tableOutput("all_cols"),width = 100),
      uiOutput("checkboxes")
    )))

dbHeader <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Exercise')

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dbHeader,
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=260*1024^2)

  db <- reactiveVal(list())

  computations <- function(){
    req(input$checkboxes)
    do.call(cbind, lapply(db(), "[", , 2)) %>%
      select_if(names(.) %in% input$checkboxes)
  }

  observeEvent(input$csvs, {
    db(lapply(input$csvs$datapath, fread))
  })

  output$numfiles <- renderText(paste("Number of files: ", length(db())))

  output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
    choice_list <- unlist(lapply(db(), function(x) colnames(x)[2]))
    checkboxGroupInput("checkboxes", "Columns to keep:", choices = choice_list, selected = choice_list)
  })

  output$all_cols <- renderTable(computations(), align = 'c', rownames = TRUE, colnames = TRUE, digits = 3)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need your `checkboxGroupInput` to be reactive. That requires a combination of `renderUI` on your server script, and `uiOutput` on your ui script.